# Embed javascript as base64

Tags: javascript, embed, base64

I'm working on a small GreaseMonkey script where I would like to embed a jQuery plugin (Markitup) so that the script is fully self contained (images + js) except for jQuery which is served from google.

I found the site http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64 which says that you can embed javascript with the href if you base64 encode the script, much like serving images as basse64 from CSS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="data:text/javascript;base64,dmFyIHNjT2JqMSA9IG5ldyBzY3Jv..."></script>
```

So i tried that but couldn't get it to work at all, using Firefox 3.0.5 on OS X.

I put together a small test page to isolate the problem but couldn't get it to work at that page either.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <script href="data:text/javascript;base64,YWxlcnQoJ2FzYWRhc2QnKTsK"></script> 
      <script>alert('a');</script>  
   </body>
</html>
```

The base64 string (YWxlcnQoJ2FzYWRhc2QnKTsK) says `alert('asadasd');` so I'm supposed to get two alerts but the only one I see is the second one where the alert is located as text inside the script tag.

Am I doing something wrong or why isn't this working, any ideas?

Comment: Question: Why do you want to base64 encode the script? It makes the file larger.

Comment: Actually, no idea. I just tries to copy & paste the whole jquery addon to the bottom of my grease monkey script and that worked fine. Guess you learn something every day, thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you put the script between the script-tags then? No need to base64-encode it, and it will be fewer bytes, easier to update etc...

Comment: Awesome! didn't know this was even possible!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

maybe just a thought but maybe the "href" should be "src" instead.

Comment: Thanks, the example on the site is wrong and I never thought about checking that.

Answer (score 6):

If you'd check script tag syntax you'd get

```
<script src="..."
        ^^^
        src NOT href
```

Using data URIs here doesn't work in IE 6 btw.

Answer (score 2):

That's funny, I am working on precisely the same problem: making a Greasemonkey script to add markItUp to all textareas of a page.

Now, I don't have an issue with the library script itself. I don't see why you want to insert it as Base64, anyway. As pointed out, it will be larger.
You can put it directly in the GM script if you want (some people do that with jQuery), or add dynamically a `<script src="someURL"></script>` to the document and wait for loading (there are numerous examples of that on the Net)(inconvenience: creates a traffic on the sites holding the files), or, like I am currently trying, using the latest (0.8) feature of GM:

```
// @require      jquery.js
// @require      markitup.js
// @resource     miuStyle style.css
```

The required JS files are automatically loaded into the GM script from a local copy, which is fast and always available. Don't use the packed versions, they don't work here. I also had issues with set.js so I just put in directly in the script.
It works well, but I don't have style nor icons yet.
I must put the miuStyle text in the Web page, I think, and change it so all background images refer to the same image hosted on Photobucket or similar, with offset. I haven't found a way to use local images (in CSS), alas, even with @resource.

My response doesn't address your problem, alas (but John's remark seems valid), but it might put you to another, simpler solution.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried to copy & paste the whole markitup and that worked fine. I'm already using require for jquery, served from google, but including markitup directly in the script because I don't want to serve it from my server. Style I append with a style tag to head and the pictures in css base64.

Comment: Reminder: @require load the file only once, when the user script is installed. After that, it lives on the user's profile on its hard disk, and each use of the script makes no hit on the server.
I suspected I could use base64 encode images in CSS but I haven't looked at the syntax yet.

Answer (score -5):

Base-64 makes the file larger, but it makes it more machine readable so it actually increases pagespeed.  I can definitely see why you'd want this, unless you want to look at 50 lines of gibberish in your file.  FYI, I just read a study that base 64 actually loads slower on mobile so if your app is heavy mobile I'd stay away